# Nestjs 13 custom layout didn't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I use NextJs 13 to build my project.

I want CustomLayout as the whole website's Layout.

There's no error anymore but CustomLayout doesn't show up.

But it only show `<Home/>` page.

How can let user click menu in CustomLayout, and it will only change `{page}`?

app/CustomLayout.tsx

```
'use client'
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import './globals.css'
import './index.scss'
import Menu from '@/app/components/Menu'
import PrelodingPage from '@/app/components/Preloading'
import Cursor from '@/app/components/cursor/CustomCursor'
import CursorManager from '@/app/components/cursor/CursorManager'

export default function Layout(props: any) {
  const [preloading, setPreloading] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [menuToggle, setMenuToggle] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const intervalRef: { current: NodeJS.Timeout | null } = useRef(null)
  const clear = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current as NodeJS.Timeout)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setPreloading(false)
    }, 3000)
    intervalRef.current = id
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!preloading) {
      clear()
    }
  }, [preloading])

  const classes = menuToggle ? 'menu-button active' : 'menu-button'

  return (
    <CursorManager>
      {preloading ? (
        <PrelodingPage />
      ) : (
        <div className='main'>
          <>
            <button
              className={classes}
              onClick={() => setMenuToggle(!menuToggle)}
            >
              <span className='bar'></span>
            </button>
            <Cursor />
            <Menu menuToggle={menuToggle} setMenuToggle={setMenuToggle} />
          </>
        </div>
      )}
    </CursorManager>
  )
}
```

app/page.tsx

```
import type { ReactElement } from 'react'
import Layout from './layout'
import CustomLayout from './CustomLayout'
import Home from './home/page'
import type { NextPageWithLayout } from './_app'

const Page: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
  return <Home />
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <CustomLayout>{page}</CustomLayout>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Next js 13 layout

The root layout is defined at the top level of the app directory and applies to all routes. This layout enables you to modify the initial HTML returned from the server.

> you can't add custom names like `CustomLayout.tsx`. The layout should be only names as `layout.tsx/jsx`

> Layouts should always pass down the `children` prop because of their nested  structure

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Next js 13 layout [`documentation`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts)

### Your Code Should Be Like This

`app/layout.tsx`

> The root layout is defined at the top level of the app directory and applies to all routes. This layout enables you to modify the initial HTML returned from the server.

```
'use client'
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import './globals.css'
import './index.scss'
import Menu from '@/app/components/Menu'
import PrelodingPage from '@/app/components/Preloading'
import Cursor from '@/app/components/cursor/CustomCursor'
import CursorManager from '@/app/components/cursor/CursorManager'

export default function Layout({ children }: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [preloading, setPreloading] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [menuToggle, setMenuToggle] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const intervalRef: { current: NodeJS.Timeout | null } = useRef(null)
  const clear = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current as NodeJS.Timeout)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setPreloading(false)
    }, 3000)
    intervalRef.current = id
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!preloading) {
      clear()
    }
  }, [preloading])

  const classes = menuToggle ? 'menu-button active' : 'menu-button'

  return (
    <CursorManager>
      {preloading ? (
        <PrelodingPage />
      ) : (
        <div className='main'>
          <>
            <button
              className={classes}
              onClick={() => setMenuToggle(!menuToggle)}
            >
              <span className='bar'></span>
            </button>
            <Cursor />
            <Menu menuToggle={menuToggle} setMenuToggle={setMenuToggle} />
          </>
        </div>
      ):
    {children}
    }
    </CursorManager>
  )
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! I adjust {children} to inside of main now works perfect!